# How do I know which method/class is called when I test java GUI in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, call, monitor

I am a beginner using eclipse for java programming. Recently I downloaded certain source code online and ran it in eclipse successfully. I want to learn how it runs. However, I failed to find a way to monitor the progress during the program running. For example, if I run the application and click certain button in the application GUI, how do I know which class/method is called? In other words, how can I use eclipse to monitor the process of program running?

Comment: By using the debug perspective .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is to use the debugger.  For example, set a breakpoint in some method and then use "Debug As" instead of "Run As" to run the application within Eclipse.

Here are a couple of tutorials / articles on using the Eclipse Debugger.

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/
- http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint(double click the left side of the line) on your method to be debugged and debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put breakpoints in the code lines you need to look and run the application in the Debug mode then it'll wait at the relevant code lines you need to check.